# Setting PlaceholderText for ContentControl object within a custom XML mapping file

Tags: xml, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

So I've recently discovered the benefits of ContentControl objects and the XML-mapping tool in word.

Since I'm trying to create a template for some legal documents, using this will save a lot of time for future projects. What I've done so far is creating a custom XML file looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<UpphandlingXMLnode xmlns="UpphandlingsXML">
<Kund></Kund>
<Datum></Datum>
<Version></Version>
<Anbudsportal></Anbudsportal>
</UpphandlingXMLnode>
```

Then I've imported the file in word, through the developer tab and the XML-mapping pane.

After that I've inserted for instance the field "Kund" as a text-field. The field then have a placeholder text "Fill in text of bla bla bla..." as a custom text. What I'd like to do is change this PlaceholderText by default tied to this XML field. Is there a way of achieving this by setting this property for instance inside the xml file?

I know I can change the text by setting the "Design mode" to on but this change doesn't stick when I import this field in another place in the document.

I'd also like to set the tag and title fields if possible in the XML file.

Comment: The XML Mapping is only for the text content of a content control. There's no direct way to map any other properties such as placeholder text, title or tag. I'm not sure how much time it could save, but VBA code could write the values in the XML file into these properties. The information would be static, however.

Comment: That's what I suspected, thank you for your answer. Seems like placing the ContentControl, changing the placeholder text, tag and title and then copying the Content control to where I want it is the easiest way to go.